# Microprocessing Stack Quesiton

Tags: microprocessor

So we are using the Motorola 68HC11 Instuction set. I have the following example I am just asking if I have the answer correct. The load x with the data located at x changed x such that it is no longer referring to the stack pointer value. So loadAB is now mistakenly looking at the memory location $1410.

[image]

Comment: As this looks like homework you need to show us what you've achieved so far and where you are stuck, so we can offer the help you need.

Comment: @BrianDrummond He *has* shown what he's achieved/deduced so far. He's merely asking for confirmation.

Comment: @TisteAndii : that was not the case when I commented. I agree it is now.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. In solution 2:

- `TSX` caused index register X to be loaded with `SP + 1` i.e. stack pointer + 1. So the value of X is currently a memory address `(SP + 1)`
- Then `LDX $0,X` loads the 2-byte value beginning at memory location `X + 0` into index register X. So X no longer contains an address but the value `$1410`.
- `LDAB $2,X` attempts to load the byte at memory location `X + 2` into accumulator B. But X no longer contains the address we expect (`SP + 1`) but a number (`$1410`) which, if used as an address, will point to some unknown number in memory (if it's even within the address space).

So the program will give unexpected results.